# UNDEFINED - multiple return values from PHP with jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Because I get undefined.  Where I am failing?

Code:

```
    function add(id,cost){
            var info = {
                    "id" : id,
                    "cost": cost,
            };
            $.ajax({
                    data:  info,
                    url:   'a.php',
                    type:  'post',
                    success:  function (datos) {
                             alert(datos+"\n r1: "+datos.r1+"\n r2:"+datos.r2);
                    }
            });
    }
```

archive a.php
PHP:

```
    $cost=$_POST['id']*$_POST['cost'] + 137;
    echo json_encode(array("r1" =>$_POST['id'], "r2" => $cost));
```

[image]

Comment: please console.log(datos)

Comment: make a console.log(datos) and you will see, that this is still a string, not yet a json! so transfor it first via `jsdatos = JSON.parse(datos);`

Comment: so go for Clayton solution `datos = JSON.parse( datos );`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you think `$.ajax` will understand `datos` as a JSON? You need to specify it, you can do it using several ways.

**Parsing it**

```
    success:  function (datos) {
      datos = JSON.parse(datos);
      alert(datos+"\n r1: "+datos.r1+"\n r2:"+datos.r2);
    }
```

**Specifying in `$.ajax` itself**

```
$.ajax({
                    data:  info,
                    url:   'a.php',
                    type:  'post',
                    dataType:"json",
      ....
```

**Setting header in PHP (doesn't work for < IE8)**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

I would suggest you to use a combination of first one and third one. Lets not leave any stone unturned.

Comment: Small note - `Content-Type: application/json` does not work for IE8 if you plan to support that browser.

Comment: That is why i mentioned `I would suggest you to use a combination of first one and third one.`.

Comment: That won't work for IE8 since it will still prompt to download (horrible browser bug), you still need to set the content type to `Content-Type: text/html`.  Most people don't support IE8 so it's probably not an issue for most folks.

Comment: @Clayton ohh i didn't know about this.

Answer (score 1):

Datos is probably a string

You can do:

```
datos = JSON.parse( datos );
```

Or, you can set the return type to JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    data:  info,
    dataType: 'json',
    url:   'a.php',
    type:  'post',
    success:  function (datos) {
    alert(datos+"\n r1: "+datos.r1+"\n r2:"+datos.r2);
    }
});
```